# Rails CSV exporting into excel produces special Â and &amp characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a rails project which is exporting some csv data into excel. On some instances excel is outputting special characters.

ex.

```
test 1 & test 2 & test 2
```

reads in excel as

```
test 1 &amp; test 2 &amp; test 2Â
```

My default CSV encoding is set to UTF-8 and I have played around with a number of other encoding settings although none of them have seemed to solve this issue.

Here is where the csv gets generated.

```
<% headers = default_headers %>
<%= CSV.generate_line(headers).strip %>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <% has_permission = @_controller.is_activity_permissioned_to_user?(activity, current_user) %>
  <% row = activity_generate_csv_row_data(activity, headers, has_permission, preferences) %>
  <%= CSV.generate_line(row).gsub(/\A""/,'').strip.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller.

```
format.csv {
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"
      {report_name}.csv\""
      headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
    }
```

Every solution i've tried has failed. I really just can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate a Byte Order Mark string with your CSV string, like:

```
BOM = "\uFEFF"

  def some_csv_string_generating_func
    ...
    return BOM + a_csv_string
  end
```

This will make Excel show the CSV file correctly.

Also, I would advice against having all the CSV generation logic/code on the view, but on a helper class/module or the like.